# Add a new method or use one method with nullable parameter?

Tags: java

I can define two methods:

```
verifyPassengerInTrain(Integer trainId)

verifyPassengerInCompartments(Integer trainId, Integer[] selectedCompartments)
```

or I can add one method that handles both cases with internal logic:

```
verifyPassenger(Integer trainId, Integer[] selectedCompartments) {
    if(selectedCompartments == null || selectedCompartments.length == 0) {
       // Need to verify the passenger in the entire train and update the below method
       // update train.processedAllCompartments(true);  
     } else {
       // verify the passenger in the given train id and in the given compartments
     }  
 }
```

The problem in having one method is that parameters don't convey the objective properly. So I prefer to use two methods.

Which way would be a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add both methods as they serve an different purpose. From your point of view, this may be something you are working on as a homework assignment or practice, and you will be the only developer.

However, in practical applications, multiple developers may not have equal familiarity with code. Therefore, defining methods that are self-explanatory is much more important than code brevity, especially when the meaning of results vary greatly depending on the inputs, as in this case.

This becomes even more apparent when some people may only have access to your Javadoc or methods as part of an API. Compare the following two implementations you have proposed.

```
// verifies whether or not a passenger is on a train if there are no selected compartments, or within the selected compartments if compartments are provided
verifyPassenger(Integer trainId, Integer[] selectedCompartments);
```

Splitting into two methods creates what can be considered a pair of self-commenting methods.

```
verifyPassengerInTrain(Integer trainId);
verifyPassengerInCompartments(Integer trainId, Integer[] selectedCompartments);
```

There is very little question what these two methods do without any sort of commenting guiding the user.